# ftp_put(): Ok to send data triggering php error

Tags: php, ftp

I have a PHP script that connects to a FTP Server (via `TLS/SSL Explicit Encryption`) and upload a file.

This script has been working fine until this morning. On our script, we have a global error/exception handler and we started to receive the following error:

## Error : ftp_put(): Ok to send data.

This is my upload function code:

```
private function upload($file_name) {
    $upload_status = [
        'Success' => false,
        'Message' => ''
    ];
    $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($this->ftpConfig['Host'], $this->ftpConfig['Port'], 30);
    if (!$conn_id) {
        $upload_status['Message'] = 'Failed to connect to FTP Server';
        return $upload_status;
    }
    $logged_in = ftp_login($conn_id, $this->ftpConfig['Username'], $this->ftpConfig['Password']);
    if (!$logged_in) {
        $upload_status['Message'] = 'Failed to login at the FTP Server';
        return $upload_status;
    }
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
    $upload_error = '';
    if (!ftp_put($conn_id, '/product/'. basename($file_name), $file_name, FTP_ASCII)) {
        $upload_error = 'Failed to upload file '. basename($file_name) .' to FTP Server';
    }
    ftp_close($conn_id);
    if (!empty($upload_error)) {
        $upload_status['Message'] = $upload_error;
        return $upload_status;
    } else {
        $upload_status['Success'] = true;
        return $upload_status;
    }
}
```

As you can see, PASSIVE mode is enabled yet we are receiving this error. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: `ftp_ssl_connect` will use a secure connection and expects server certificate to be updated. Maybe your certificate has expired or you are using a no longer valid user/pass. Try ftp_connect instead.

Comment: The connection works fine in WinSCP. If I use `ftp_connect` (instead of ftp_ssl_connect), I get this error `ftp_login(): Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.`. the ftp server is ran by a third party and they've asked us to connect via ssl only.

Comment: Show us a session log file from WinSCP showing an upload of the same file in the ascii mode.